# How to get orders array in magento 2 in custom module?

Tags: magento-2.0

I need orders array in custom module controller. how to get that?

tried this, but didn't work:

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection(); echo "";            
print_r($orderCollection);
```

Error:

"Fatal error: Class 'WebHive\SPS\Controller\Index\Mage' not found in C:\wamp\www\magento_test\app\code\WebHive\SPS\Controller\Index\Index.php on line 76"

All suggestions would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

May be following could be helpful for you. 
Try this code in your controller function

```
    require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
    Mage::app(); 
    $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
```